# 'Column' object is not callable after groupBy and aggregation in Pyspark

Tags: dataframe, pyspark

I have the following dataframe.

docid_ province
123       zhejiang
123        zhejiang
123        shanghai
456.       zhejiang

I want to find the most frequent province for each docid.
so I first groupBy docid and then count the frequency. But I got the error of
'Column' object is not callable

This is my code:

```
uin_feature_province_count = uin_feature.groupBy("docid_").\
    agg(col("province").groupBy("province").count().orderBy(col("province").desc).collect()(0).get(0).alias("most_province"))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't tried to fix your code but if just you need most common province for each doc id you can try using row number over count of province as done below

```
uin_feature_province_count = uin_feature.groupBy("docid_","province").agg(row_number().over(Window.partitionBy("docid_").orderBy(count("province").desc())).alias("rank")).filter(col("rank")==1).select("docid_","province")
```